# I need some info about forming my inquiries and questions, so I can get assistance

Tags: android

I just had a post flagged, and voted down. It wasn't even up for a minute and a moderator closed it. When some one has an app that is crashing, what is the proper  info to provide, in order to recieve help. I just learned how to use some of the logcat features to help my diagnostics. What else could I provide?

(1) I have an app, and I believe I know what function is executing when it hangs.
(2) I have info provided to me in the debug window(I do not know how to interpret the info)
(3) I have logcat info.

Can someone help me with understanding what else I need to do? Getting my post closed, flagged, or voted down, before I can converse with someone is frustrating.

I have real questions, and can narrow them down, if I can get a few pointers.

Comment: I have a question that was closed just a few minutes ago by a moderator, it's just down the page a bit. I provided info from the debugger, but maybe it wasn't useful enough, or just wasn't enough info. either way I feel it was closed a bit prematuraly. The frustrating part is I can only post or reply to my question every 20 minutes

Comment: In general your questions are too broad. Take a look at the FAQ to understand the kinds of questions that are suited to stackoverlfow. As in this case you are basically asking someone to hold your hand through every step of debugging rather than asking a specific question. There are other sites (or books) that are probably better suited to tutorials. This is not a forum the older style of message boards. Also rather than opening new questions each time you get further keep following up with more information on the original question by editing the post and adding comments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help folks. I decided to try and clean up some of the questions I've posted or delete them all together if they didn't seem all that great, clean up the forum a bit. Well since I deleted 5 of my post, I have been banned from asking anymore questions until I get some up votes. So If someone could kindly give me an upvote here, I can get back into the game, learn, and hopefully help others in the future. Please Help! Upvote this question!

Answer (score 1):

Providing log cat info is helpful.  I would only post the part of the log that is labeled as an error.  You also need to be solving a specific problem.  Don't just post a question asking why your app is crashing.  Look up the line number in your logcat and ask why a specific line isn't working.  If you don't know how to determine what line number the problem is on, I would suggest asking that, because locating the problem is a very important step in solving errors in android.

Comment: Thankyou, I agree 100%, I have my own logcat filter I use for some messages I've created my self, but getting the regular logcat to pause isn't working for me, not sure how to do it. Well, I just unplugged the phone, that stopped it! Now I see the logcat has 4 categories, Time, PID, Tag, and Message. It's quite alot of info, is there a way to copy it so I can paste the error?

Comment: How do you determine the line number the problem is on?

Comment: The stack trace in logcat should indicate a line in your code.

Comment: Where do I find the stack trace? I do believe I know which is the error. I found it by creating a Log message for each of my functions. One message when entering a function and one when leaving a function. When my app failed to leave a function as expected, I noted the time of the custom enter message and crossed refrenced it with the general logcat. But anyway, how do I view the stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace is output in logcat when your app crashes.